# Reason provided by the contract: "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"

Tags: solidity, web3js, openzeppelin

I'm new to solidity and I wanted to develop a subscription contract where a user can subscribe to a merchants plan and pay. But I'm unable to subscribe function and transfer the token to merchant.

I'm using open zeppelin ERC20 standard token to transfer.

```
    IERC20 token = IERC20(plans[planId].token);
    token.transferFrom(
        payable(msg.sender),
        payable(plan.merchant),
        plan.amount
    );
```

I don't know why but this keeps giving me allowance error even though I have increased the allowance of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're invoking the `token.transferFrom()` from the subscription contract, the token owner needs to `increaseAllowance()` for the subscription contract to manipulate their tokens.

Example:

- Your subscription contract is deployed on address `0x123`.
- Token address is `0x456`, and it has `18` decimals.
- The user needs to execute `increaseAllowance(0x123, 500 * 1e18)` on the token contract in order to increase the allowance by 500 tokens.

  - *Mind the subscription contract address as the first param, and the decimals as the second param (so the actual value passed to the second param is `500000000000000000000` because it includes the decimals as units as well).*

Comment: ok so you mean that i need to give tokens to the contract? if so, why? because the contract is called by the user who has token and increased allowance . Am i missing some basics please guide TIA

Comment: It worked finally. I was just missing zero's . Feeling like a noob